# How to Add One event to each Item On A CheckboxList Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, event-handling

How Can I Add One Event to Each item On A CheckBoxList, pr example I Wanto to add One Click Event to check What Item Has been checked.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in CheckBoxList is of type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem` and has *no events* defined.

Comment: so there no way to know when any item are clicked or checked?

Comment: @BlaShadow Even if it were possible, every check/uncheck would require a round-trip to server which may not be so good.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit tricky with the CheckBoxList. Don't think there's a straight way to add an click-event to each item, since the ListItem-class doesn't have any events.

You could set `AutoPostBack="true"` on the CheckBoxList and check on page load which items are selected, but you wouldn't know easy which was the last one clicked.

Other solution is to get rid of the CheckBoxList and create just CheckBoxes and set the click-event on those to the same event-method. And there you could check the sender.

ASPX:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="A" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_Clicked" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" Text="B" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_Clicked" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" Text="C" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_Clicked" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(((CheckBox)sender).Text);
}
```

Or you could make your own custom CheckBoxList that handles click-events on items.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I found this question/answer and it didn't help me out. While the provided answer is correct, there is an easy way to build a CheckBoxList-like control witha  Repeater control.

Turns out that you can use a Repeater with an ItemTemplate with a CheckBox. 
 I have a complete explanation here: http://www.rhyous.com/2014/10/17/aspx-checkboxlist-alternative-that-allows-for-the-oncheckedchanged-event/

I also copied the needed data here in this answer:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CheckBoxListExample._Default" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="CheckBoxListExample" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="CheckBoxListExample.Models" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RepeaterCheckBoxChanged"
                    Text="<%# ((CheckBoxViewModel)Container.DataItem).Name %>"
                    Checked="<%# ((CheckBoxViewModel)Container.DataItem).IsChecked %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CheckBoxListExample.Models;

namespace CheckBoxListExample
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        private List<CheckBoxViewModel> _ViewModels;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var _ViewModels = new List<CheckBoxViewModel>
                {
                    new CheckBoxViewModel {Name = "Test1", IsChecked = true},
                    new CheckBoxViewModel {Name = "Test2"},
                    new CheckBoxViewModel {Name = "Test3"}
                };
                Repeater1.DataSource = _ViewModels;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void RepeaterCheckBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cb = sender as CheckBox;
            if (cb == null) return;
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                // Insert
            }
            else
            {
                // Delete
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CheckBoxViewModel**

```
namespace CheckBoxListExample.Models
{
    public class CheckBoxViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```